# Make a new column in R or bash

Tags: r

I have antibody data the first column is heavy chain sequence and the second column is the light chain

I want to create a third column by combining two columns like

If `CARGRGIAVAGTTGFDYW` is a heavy chain and `CQQYNSYSLTF` a light chain, in third column I want `CARGRGIAVAGTTGFDYW_CQQYNSYSLTF`

if a heavy or light chain is absent, I want something like `NA_CQQYNSYSLTF` or `CARGRGIAVAGTTGFDYW_NA` depends of absent part

```
CDR3.light.aa   CDR3.heavy.aa
-              CAGDLSVGGVLAGGVPHLRHFDPW
-              CPETPRYCSGGFCYGEFDNW

CSSYAGSNTFGLF   -
CSSYAGSNTGLF    -
```

So far I have done this

```
a$a <- paste(a$CDR3.heavy.aa, a$CDR3.light.aa, sep= "_")
```

But I noticed a lot of mess and manual works

Any help please?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Thank you, I have added my code in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach was correct, you just have to transform your dataframe first to replace the character "-" by NA :

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df=data.frame(CDR3.light.aa=c("-","-","CSSYAGSNTFGLF",'CSSYAGSNTGLF'),
              CDR3.heavy.aa=c("CAGDLSVGGVLAGGVPHLRHFDPW","-","CPETPRYCSGGFCYGEFDNW","-"))

df=df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "-", "NA")))      


df$a <- paste(df$CDR3.heavy.aa, df$CDR3.light.aa, sep= "_")


 df
  CDR3.light.aa            CDR3.heavy.aa                                  a
1            NA CAGDLSVGGVLAGGVPHLRHFDPW        CAGDLSVGGVLAGGVPHLRHFDPW_NA
2            NA                       NA                              NA_NA
3 CSSYAGSNTFGLF     CPETPRYCSGGFCYGEFDNW CPETPRYCSGGFCYGEFDNW_CSSYAGSNTFGLF
4  CSSYAGSNTGLF                       NA                    NA_CSSYAGSNTGLF
```